# Representation of symmetric functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, symmetric-functions

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that every symmetric function $f\colon E^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be written in the form $f(x) = g\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i} \Bigr)$, where $g$ has to be chosen appropriately (dependent on $f$).

$E$ is an arbitrary Polish space.

First I asked about the meaning of "$g$". Since we have concluded that it is a map
$$g\colon \mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{fin}} (E) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
where $\mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{fin}}(E)$ means the space of all finite measures on $(E,\mathcal{B}(E))$, it's now about solving the exercise.

We have to find a way to "extract" as much information about the vector $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in E^n$ from the measure $\mu := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}$ as possible.

Since $E$ is a Polish space, there exists a countable, dense subset $Z= \{z_1, z_2, \ldots\}$ of $E$. Define the countable family of sets $$\mathcal{S}_\varepsilon := \{ B_\varepsilon(z_i)\in \mathcal{B}(E): \mu\bigl(B_\varepsilon(z_i)\bigr)>0 \text{ and } z_i \in Z\}\, ,$$
then $$ R := \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty\; \bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{S}_{1/m}} S \, .$$

Now $R = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, though we don't get any information about the original order of the elements. Assume $R$ consists of different $r_1, \ldots, r_k \in E$ with $k \leq n$. We construct a vector $\vec{v}_\mu\in E^n$ by
$$ \vec{v}_\mu := (\underbrace{r_1, \ldots, r_1}_{n \mu(r_1)-\text{times}}, \ldots, \underbrace{r_k, \ldots, r_k}_{n \mu(r_k)-\text{times}})\, ,$$
so the number of occurrences of an $x_i$ is the same in $\vec{v}_\mu$ and $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

Since $f$ is symmetric, which means
$$ f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_{\rho(1)}, \ldots, x_{\rho(n)}) \quad \forall \rho \in S_n \, ,$$
we also have
$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(\vec{v}_\mu)\, ,$$
this defines the map $g(\mu) := f(\vec{v}_\mu)$ (aside from the detail that we also have to arbitrarily define $g$ for all the measures we don't care about; only probability measures of the form $\mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{x_i}$ are important). $\square$

Is that ok?

Comment: How do probability measures enter this scene at all? And since $E$ is supposed to be Polish, I assume $f$ (and $g$ and $\delta_{x_i}$?) are supposed to be continuous?

Comment: I really don't know. I find this passage in my textbook extremely confusing.. see here: https://books.google.com/books?id=xDy3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=klenke+exercise+%2212.1.1%22

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: If you could help me here, that would be so nice!! I'm completely stuck.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Is there any interpretation of $\delta_{x_i}$ other than the Dirac measure, i.e. $\delta_{x_i}(A) = 1$ if $x_i \in A$,  $\delta_{x_i}(A) = 0$ if $x_i \not\in A$?

Comment: Where is the mystery in this textbook's statement? There is no need to hypothesize unusual meanings of the symbols, of course here $\delta_x$ **is** the Dirac measure at $x$, the real-valued function $f$ is defined on $E^n$ and the real-valued function $g$ should be defined on the space of (positive finite) measures $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$. Example: If $E=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=\min\limits_ix_i$ for every $x=(x_i)$  then one can choose $$g(\mu)=\sup\{t\in\mathbb R\mid\mu((-\infty,t))=0\}.$$

Comment: @Did: Well, the strange, non-obvious part was that $g$ is a function on the space of positive finite measures. How should one know this without guessing? Shouldn't that be mentioned somewhere? Ok, who cares, it's clear now, thanks.

Comment: This does seem obvious as soon as one meets (and takes seriously) something like $g\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i} \Bigr)$, no?

Comment: @Did: Is this some kind of psychological research now?

Comment: ??? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did: Well, your question is not mathematical but about human cognition: Why do humans sometimes miss obvious interpretations? It could be many reasons: Lack of confidence, intelligence, etc. or they had misleading information. I think here it was the last one: The space of finite measures is defined twenty pages later in this book, so it was surprising for me that the definition is preceded by the first usage. Anyway I'm trying a solution now and if I post it we hopefully can discuss mathematical questions again.