# Doubt in definition of symmetric continuous function and norm in Kupka's paper

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-topology, multilinear-algebra, morse-theory

In this article "[Counterexample to the Morse-Sard theorem in the case of infinite-dimensional manifolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-05/S0002-9939-1965-0182024-4/S0002-9939-1965-0182024-4.pdf)" of I. Kupka has the following passage:

For $H=l^{2}$

"Let $H^{*}$ be the dual of $H$. A base of $H^{*}$ is formed by the linear functions $e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{n},...$ where

$e_{n}(x)=x_{n}$ where $x= (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k},...)$

For any $k$, let $\sum_{k}(H^{*})$ be the space of all $k$-linear symmetric continuous functions on $H$.  $\sum_{k}(H^{*})$ is also Hilbert space, with norm $||.||_{k}$."

My doubts:

a) What is $k$-linear **symmetric** continuous functions on $H$?
Precisely, what does **symmetric** mean? Is it $T(x,y,z)= T(z,y,x)$ for $x,y,z \in H$?

b) Which norm  $||.||_{k}$ is this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to advertise this counterexample due to Robert Bonic, which I find much more appealing than Kupka's.

Consider $E=C^0([0,1])$ and $G:E\rightarrow E$ which sends $G(f)(x)=f(x)^3$. Then $G$ is smooth and $dG(f)(u)=3f^2 u$. Thus if $f$ has a zero, $f$ is a critical point for $G$. Now set
$$
C=\{f\in E\,|f(x)<0,\quad f(y)>0,\quad \text{for some}\quad x,y\in[0,1]\}
$$
Note that any $f\in C$ has a zero, and that $C$ is open. Moreover $G(C)= C$ hence the set of critical values of $G$ contains an open set.

Comment: Hi,it's very interesting. I had a difficulty to show that $dG(f)(u)(.) = 3(f(.))^{2}u(.)$ is the derivative of $G$ in $f$. I consider the uniform norm.
We must to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that for $||h||< \delta$ we have that $||G(f+h) - G(f) - G'(f)(h) ||<\epsilon ||h||$. But I stuck here.Thank you

Comment: $G(f+h)-G(f)-3f^2h=3fh^2+h^3=(3f h+h^2) h$. Now, the sup norm of $3fh+h^2$ can be made as small as we want, by taking $\delta>0$ small. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I found the definition to  $k$-linear symmetric, here [Representation of symmetric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228468/representation-of-symmetric-functions?rq=1).

And the norm $||.||_{k}$, http://www.math.uni-oldenburg.de/preprints/get/source/flo-gar.pdf page 2. Just change $k=2$ for $k$ arbitrary.